# Redirection to a different host without changing the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, symfony-1.4

I have a vHost where the main website is called coffee.loc at port 8002.
The website is supposed to be inside an intranet network, where there are specific links that need to be available for users outside of the intranet.

There is a specific address "http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12" (or any other drinkid value)  and another similar one which need to be allowed to access.

I have another vHost called redirect.loc at port 8888.

When accessing redirect.loc, the document root path is actually specified to be the root of coffee.loc. So by accessing redirect.loc we are actually accessing coffe.loc homepage. In the functionality of the homepage, based on the url a redirect is happening to the specific link.

So, once I access redirect.loc it's supposed to show the page available at:
http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12 and it's doing so, however the URL is not supposed to change. It should be redirect.loc:8888 through the browsing, if the first request came from it.

I saw similar discussions on this topic, however none of them seemed to work. Once I was able to make a redirection without URL change, but the loading of files (css, js, images etc) were all wrong because Symfony read the root url to be http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12 so I was getting errors 404 constantly.

I am using Symfony 1.4 and Apache2

EDIT:

I was able to make a redirection without URL change, but the loading of files (css, js, images etc) were all wrong because and returned error 404. I was using Proxy, and when I set proxy for redirect.loc to be set to coffee.loc:8002 it worked fine, I was seeing the start page of coffee.loc. However if I try to use the specific link in proxy set up, the page and all the requests end up with a status 404.

This is the set up for proxy:

```
<Proxy>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
  Allow from 203.0.113.67
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12
ProxyPassReverse / http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12
```

Comment: Well, a redirection _always_ changes the URL visible in the browser, because it is a command sent to the browser which says: please load that URL instead.

Comment: The usual setup for such things is not redirection (or rewriting), but a reverse proxy acting as a frontend for the internal service. Did you take a look at that option? The apache http server offers a proxy module. You can even embed it in the rewriting module.

Comment: `I am using Symfony 1.4` - you know that this hasn't seen updates since years? I'd better not ask about which PHP version you are running.....

Comment: @arkascha Yeah I didn't write that correctly in my question - when I managed to pull off a proper loading of the page, but leaving the url unchanged - I was using proxy. However that's when the files did not load properly due to root url being read as a link that's supposed to show.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I'm aware of that and i hate the 1.4 version but it is how it is I cannot change it :) Not to get into it, the PHP version is 7.3

Comment: _“because Symfony read the root url to be `http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12`”_ - well that _is_ the base URL you specified in your ProxyPass directive. Of course this won’t work, if you expect the proxy to work for other URLs, that don’t start with this kind of “prefix”. Your proxy should rather point to just `http://coffe.loc:8002/` here, so that it works for _all_ requests below that domain. If you need `redirect.loc:8888/` to show the content of `http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12`, then find some other way to facilitate the latter.

Comment: @CBroe That's exactly why I am here. Even if I set the proxy to the root of the coffee.loc:8002, it shows the start page correctly without any issues, but  I don't know which way I can show the content of the `http://coffe.loc:8002/drink?&drinkid=12` without changing the URL (`redirect.loc:8888`) and is it even possible.

Comment: Can’t you just configure `coffe.loc` to make that its “default” page to begin with? So that it doesn’t need to get these parameters passed, to show the proper entry point?

Comment: Running a reverse proxy is the correct solution for when you want users on the public internet to be able to access a backend server.  However it's only going to work if your Symfony app is using relative URLs everywhere.  If the hostname coffe.loc is "hardcoded" anywhere those links and images will be delivered in the HTML with full URL and will be broken as you've described.

Comment: @CBroe No, since there is a default page that should be shown if you access with the original hostname.

Comment: @KrisPeeling It does use relative, however it loads them dinamically. So when using proxy the 'root' of the url is actually the whole path described in proxy settings.